# `brew cleanup` doesn't scrub the Caskroom

Tags: homebrew

Apparently `brew cleanup` also cleans the cask cache. But my problem was that many casks leave their installers in `/usr/local/Caskroom`, which is not considered part of the cache, and thus taking up a lot of space, while in fact the installer might not be needed after the installation.

---

Now `brew cask cleanup` is merged with `brew cleanup`.

However, I haven't found a way to purge my Caskroom folder using `brew cleanup`.

The man page says:

```
   cleanup [options] [formula|cask]
       Remove stale lock files and outdated downloads for formulae and casks, and remove old versions of installed formulae. If arguments are specified, only do
       this for the specified formulae and casks.

       --prune
              Remove all cache files older than specified days.

       -n, --dry-run
              Show what would be removed, but do not actually remove anything.

       -s     Scrub  the cache, including downloads for even the latest versions. Note downloads for any installed formula or cask will still not be deleted. If
              you want to delete those too: rm -rf "$(brew --cache)"

       --prune-prefix
              Only prune the symlinks and directories from the prefix and remove no other files.
```

I want to delete the installers for the currently installed packages as well. For example, the mactex installer takes up almost 4 GB of space.

Apparently, the command for non-cask installs is `rm -rf $(brew --cache)`, but what is the equivalent for casks?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it used to be possible to change `HOMEBREW_CLEANUP_MAX_AGE_DAYS` to, say, 0, and `*.pkg` and similar would be remove with `cleanup -s`.

For some reason, that was considered a bug in https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7320
and changed in https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/7400/files.

I say "for some reason" because it's really mysterious to me, and various people have asked about it and never gotten an answer in the Github issues.

As per that story of the fence and it's removable, you might not want to do something the maintainers consider so unthinkable that they literally can't understand what's being asked.

For everyone else,

```
 ls -la /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/**.{dmg,pkg}
```

followed by the same lime, only `rm -rf` instead of `ls -la` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the command. Seems that the wildcard pattern is not completely correct though. It didn't seem to work in either zsh or bash. Also I think the path at least in my system is `/usr/local/Caskroom`

Comment: So apparently in this issue https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/11099 they argued that the reason is that you may want to downgrade/fix a package by reinstalling a previous version. Still I think that's a stretch and there's no reason you shouldn't be able to download an old version directly when it's needed. Keeping the files around feels like a huge waste of space.

Comment: This command worked for me instead, in terms of both avoiding the problematic wildcard and not assuming the Homebrew prefix (since the one from Matthias is the default for ARM installs only): `find "$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom" -type f '(' -name '*.dmg' -or -name '*.pkg' ')' -delete`